# Javascript issue in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I'm working with a site that stopped working in Firefox randomly. This piece of code is populating into the html each time I try to update, and I'm trying to understand it. I haven't made any changes to the javascript used in the site but whatever this is has completely disabled all the site elements that use javascript. The kicker is that it only happens in Firefox. Chrome works perfectly. I've been poring over the html all day and this is the only thing that's weird- I'm at my wit's end, any ideas? I don't know a great deal about Javascript and I haven't touched anything in the scripts for the site, so I don't understand why they suddenly stopped functioning.

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="RTCEarlyScript">

window.oldSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;
window.setTimeout = function (func, delay) {
  return window.oldSetTimeout(function () {
    try {
      if (!document.documentElement.getAttribute('stopTimers ')) {
        if (typeof func == 'string') {
          var nfunc = new Function(func);
          nfunc();
        } else func();
      }
    } catch (ex) {
    }
  }, delay);
};
window.oldSetInterval = window.setInterval;
window.setInterval = function (func, delay) {
  return window.oldSetInterval(function () {
    try {
      if (!document.documentElement.getAttribute('stopTimer s')) {
        if (typeof func == 'string') {
          var nfunc = new Function(func);
          nfunc();
        } else func();
      }
    } catch (ex) {
    }
  }, delay);
};
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try removing it? It looks like you're overriding `window.setTimeout` which is not really good practice.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but can you try adding in some carriage returns to that code?  It feels a bit intimidating to try and read all of that in one line.

Comment: @styfle Yep. Every time I remove it, the next time I update the page it comes back. Oddly enough I've narrowed down the problem with functionality to a malfunctioning Firefox add-on, but since this code keeps appearing I know something else has to be wrong. Since I'm using some pre-coded modules for this site it's a bit of a tossup as to what's causing it. I can tell that there's something wrong with the code, but goodness only knows what.

Comment: What exactly is this code trying to accomplish? I feel like if I had to guess `window` is probably the culprit, especially if its a browser specific thing. Maybe you could find a different way of doing this without `window`?

Comment: why... would you do this. That aside, turn this into either SO runnable code, or a jsfiddle/jsbin, so we can see it in action and comment/correct your code?

Comment: Well as I mentioned, it's not something I did. I know next to nothing about Javascript which is why I'm asking for help- I'm working with a group on this project, they decided on using some pre-coded modules to add certain functions that they wanted instead of just hiring a coder, and now I get to troubleshoot for them. In any case, I'm just going to let them know we need to do something else.

Answer (score 1):

The [**R**ight**T**o**C**lick](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/righttoclick/)   extension is injecting that script, and obviously not cleaning up after itself.
Disable or remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this helps, but I understand the intent of the code.

`setTimeout` and `setInterval` are JavaScript functions that allow a programmer to "schedule" an event to happen at a given time. So you can execute some code a second from now, or five seconds from now.

The developer here is attempting to replace those functions with semantic equivalents that first check to see if someone has set a "stopTimers" attribute on the top-level element in the document (the `<html>` element). If that attribute is set, then the code that was scheduled to run does not run.